# Microsoft mouse like windows switcher (or anything usable)

Tags: windows-7, switch, window, alt-tab

I tried "Switcher" and the new switcher by NTSoft... but none of them are for my taste. I want to have a switcher like what you get with an Intellimouse by Microsoft. You know, press the button and get a cool tiled layout of thumbnails.

To be precise, anything is fine with me. However:

- No AERO needed (I seriously hate it.);
- Be able to switch between apps by mouse;
- Be able to make them come up in a cube (not just a row);

In a nutshell: a usable alt-tab/window switcher!

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried this one ? http://cybernetnews.com/alttab-mouse-shortcut/

Comment: Usable and eye-candy often contradict each other ;-) A lesson Apple has yet to learn and Microsoft did mostly right, if if weren't for Windows Flip 3D ... :-)

Comment: @Mgpyone: No, I also use Opera's mouse gestures. And this is not what I search for. (Got a Razer Lachesis, with enough buttons. But the software doesnt have the same shortcut as the Intellimouse).

Comment: The latest version of Intellitype supports Instant Viewer, ie. you can assign it to a keystroke (though you probably need to own a Microsoft keyboard).

Comment: For the next keyboard I wanted to get a SUN like keyboard (mechanical switches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html): tried.

There certainly are others :). Wikipedia has a [list of Exposé clones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expos%C3%A9_clone). Perhaps one of them would be suitable? You can also put two or three of them into a Google query to find web pages which list switchers.

Comment: Tried. Sadly it becomes unusable once there is a little CPU/GPU load (only on Classic Windows skin without Aero.) Maybe the developer will fix it later, but at the minute its out of the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also, if I copy something or just even put a load on my HDD, the worst usable switcher. Hope there are others out there.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the list. Playing with "Dexpot" but not the best. All apps are way too slow. Seems like there is a need for a new one which is pure C based and uses native `commands`.

Comment: okay. Dexpot kills a bunch of hotkeys (like Pidgin). :/

Comment: Sadly the help of yours didnt take me forward, but it was better than nothing. (Quite strange that a page with such/huge userbase.. and only one person tried.. well.. it happens). Anyway, you are the only one for the points, have fun. :)

Comment: @Fujishiro: I wanted to try M$ Intellipoint's "Instant Viewer" (which requires an M$ mouse) and actually asked a bounty question of my own (change USB vendor/product id) before realizing I had an old M$ mouse I could plug in :) What do you prefer about Instant Viewer vs. other progs? If you really like it, the cheapest M$ mouse is pretty affordable.

Comment: Yeah but I already got a Razer Lachesis mouse. Don't want to 'throw it out'. It costs a fortune. :/ If I would've known this, I'd rather buy a Microsoft mouse... but its too late.

Answer (score 0):

I used [TopDesk](http://www.otakusoftware.com/topdesk/) for quite a while in WinXP. It is fast and doesn't use Aero / WPF, and works even on relatively old PCs. Unfortunately, it is not free. They do have a demo though so you can play around with it to see if you like it.

Comment: Sorry its not really what I am looknig for, way too old. (Its ok for XP though.)